# How to use a Bluetooth A2DP Headset with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord (iOS 10.0)?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-audio

I'm trying to set a Bluetooth A2DP Headset as output of my audio chain. I'm setting my AudioSession with a *AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord* with the option *AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetoothA2DP*.

Apple docs says this should be possible starting in iOS 10.0 (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryoptions/avaudiosessioncategoryoptionallowbluetootha2dp) but when I execute the *AudioOutputUnitStart* my bluetooth headset dissappear from the routes selector of the MPVolumeView and I can't hear any audio. Also if I query the currents output ports the bluetooth headset now appears as a *AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver* instead as a *AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP*.